# Why is my datatable is not recognizing fnDestroy() function all of a sudden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, datatables

My code was fine but this morning it started behaving a bit different by throwing the error:

> fnDestory() is not a function

```js
$('#tblServicesReport').DataTable().fnDestroy();

$('#tblServicesReport').DataTable({
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [
    'copyHtml5',
    'excelHtml5',
    'csvHtml5',
    {
      extend: 'pdfHtml5',
      title: 'Services Report (' + $('#FromDate').val() + ' - ' + $('#ToDate').val() + ')',
      customize: function(doc) {
        doc.styles.title = {
          color: 'gray',
          fontSize: '15',
          alignment: 'center'
        }

        doc.content[1].table.widths = Array(doc.content[1].table.body[0].length + 1).join('*').split('');
        doc.styles.tableHeader.fontSize = 10;
        doc.styles.tableHeader.alignment = 'left';
        doc.styles.tableHeader.color = 'white'
      }
    },
    {
      extend: 'print'
      //title: 'Sales Report'
    }
  ]
});
```

I am using data table 1.10.15. Until today everything was working but not now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fnDestroy()` method is within the `$.fn.dataTable` scope - note the lowercase `D`. Change the code to this:

```
$('#tblServicesReport').dataTable().fnDestroy();
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/5bacb94r/)

Also note that this is not a new change, it's been the case for several years.